# Being paid for helping my friend in his graded assignment and asking him to learn afterwards. Haram?

Tags: halal-haram, sin, studying

I have Helped my friend in one of his graded assignments and he paid me. Now I offered him to teach him that topic for free, and he learns too.

Now here the student have learnt the topic and is capable to does the task in the future. The grading is also done in an absolute system unlike relative system (On curves) so no body is harmed. Plus if his degree states that he is capable to doing that task, then that's also true.

In this case no body is hurt. I'm I allowed to keep the cash?

Comment: You're teaching him as official teachers are teaching him. They also get paid for their trouble, so why shouldn't you?

Answer (score 0):

Asalaamualikum warahmatulaahi wabarakaatuh.
Brother,as you said that you helped the student in assignment but also taught him what he had to learnt related to the assignment then there is no sin in it because the student himself is trying to understand the assignment and you are just helping him in doing so.So,you can the take the money for your efforts in teaching the student,it is halaal(permissible)In sha Allah
And Allah Subhaanahu wa'ta'aala knows best.